# Adding new fields based on condition using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, conditional, qgsvectorlayer

I want to add another condition in my code.

This is my code:

```py
tablePT = QgsVectorLayer('None', 'table_PT', 'memory')
tablePT.dataProvider().addAttributes(
    [QgsField("Type", QVariant.String), QgsField("FT", QVariant.Int),
     QgsField("FREE", QVariant.Int), QgsField("PRIVE", QVariant.Int),
     ])
tablePT.updateFields()
dicoPT = {'CHAMBRE': (0, 0, 0), 'POTEAU': (0, 0, 0)}
nbPTTotal = 0
for pt in self.couchePT.getFeatures() :
    typeStruc = pt['TYPE_STRUC']
    proprietaire = pt['PROPRIETAI']
    if typeStruc in ['CHAMBRE', 'POTEAU'] :
        if proprietaire == 'FT' :
            dicoPT[typeStruc] = tuple(map(operator.add, (1, 0, 0), dicoPT[typeStruc]))
            nbPTTotal += 1
        elif proprietaire == 'FREE MOBILE' :
            dicoPT[typeStruc] = tuple(map(operator.add, (0, 1, 0), dicoPT[typeStruc]))
            nbPTTotal += 1
        elif proprietaire == 'PRIVE' :
            dicoPT[typeStruc] = tuple(map(operator.add, (0, 0, 1), dicoPT[typeStruc]))
            nbPTTotal += 1
        else:
            QMessageBox.critical(None, "Problème de PT",
                                 "Le point_technique %s possède un propriétaire qui ne fait pas partie de la liste." % str(pt['NOM']))
    else:
        QMessageBox.critical(None, "Problème de PT",
                             "Le point_technique %s possède un type de strcture qui ne fait pas partie de la liste." % str(pt['NOM']))
ligneChambre = QgsFeature()
ligneChambre.setAttributes(['chambres', dicoPT['CHAMBRE'][0], dicoPT['CHAMBRE'][1], dicoPT['CHAMBRE'][2]])
lignePoteau = QgsFeature()
lignePoteau.setAttributes(['poteaux', dicoPT['POTEAU'][0], dicoPT['POTEAU'][1], dicoPT['POTEAU'][2]])
ligneTotaux = QgsFeature()
ligneTotaux.setAttributes(['Total général', "", "", nbPTTotal])
tablePT.dataProvider().addFeatures([ligneChambre])
tablePT.dataProvider().addFeatures([lignePoteau])
tablePT.dataProvider().addFeatures([ligneTotaux])

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(tablePT)
```

This is my table for now:

[image: table]

but I want to get information based on two condition just like this:

[image]

I want a table with rows that result from two condition in the same time:

```
First row = (case when typeStruc='CHAMBRE' and ETAT='EN SERVICE') => "CHAMBRE EXISTANT"

Second row = (case when typeStruc='CHAMBRE' and ETAT='EN ETUDE') => "CHAMBRE A POSE"

Third row = (case when typeStruc='POTEAU' and ETAT='EN ETUDE') => "POTEAU EXISTANT"

Fourth row = (case when typeStruc='POTEAU' and ETAT='EN ETUDE') => "POTEAU A POSE"
```

Comment: Yes i add it but i don’t know how to add it in setattributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this script. I guess it works for you.

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("PT")[0]

tablePT = QgsVectorLayer("None", "table_PT", "memory")
tablePT.dataProvider().addAttributes(
    [QgsField("Type", QVariant.String),
     QgsField("FT", QVariant.Int),
     QgsField("FREE", QVariant.Int),
     QgsField("PRIVE", QVariant.Int)])
tablePT.updateFields()

# types    
t = ["Chambre Existant", "Chambre a poser", "Poteau Existant", "Poteau a poser"]

d = {t[0]: {"FT": 0, "FREE MOBILE": 0, "PRIVE": 0},
     t[1]: {"FT": 0, "FREE MOBILE": 0, "PRIVE": 0},
     t[2]: {"FT": 0, "FREE MOBILE": 0, "PRIVE": 0},
     t[3]: {"FT": 0, "FREE MOBILE": 0, "PRIVE": 0}}

for pt in layer.getFeatures():
    stru = pt["TYPE_STRUC"]
    etat = pt["ETAT"]
    prop = pt["PROPRIETAI"]

    if prop in ["FT", "FREE MOBILE", "PRIVE"]:
        if stru == "CHAMBRE":
            if etat == "EN SERVICE":
                d[t[0]][prop] += 1
            elif etat == "EN ETUDE":
                d[t[1]][prop] += 1
        elif stru == "POTEAU":
            if etat == "EN SERVICE":
                d[t[2]][prop] += 1
            elif etat == "EN ETUDE":
                d[t[3]][prop] += 1
        else: 
            print(f"Le point_technique {pt['NOM']} possède un type de strcture ...")            
    else:
        print(f"Le point_technique {pt['NOM']} possède un propriétaire ...")

for i in [0, 1, 2, 3]:
    feature = QgsFeature(tablePT.fields())
    feature.setAttributes([ t[i], d[t[i]]["FT"], d[t[i]]["FREE MOBILE"], d[t[i]]["PRIVE"] ])
    tablePT.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature])

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(tablePT)
```

Sample data:

| TYPE_STRUC | ETAT | PROPRIETAI | NOM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHAMBRE | EN ETUDE | FREE MOBILE | 9 |
| EN ETUDE |  | FREE MOBILE | 8 |
| POTEAU | EN ETUDE | FREE MOBILE | 7 |
| CHAMBRE | EN ETUDE | FREE MOBILE | 6 |
| CHAMBRE | EN ETUDE | FREE MOBILE | 5 |
| EN ETUDE |  | FREE MOBILE | 4 |
| CHAMBRE | EN ETUDE | FREE MOBILE | 3 |
| POTEAU | EN ETUDE |  | 2 |
| CHAMBRE | EN SERVICE | PRIVE | 15 |
| POTEAU | EN SERVICE | PRIVE | 14 |
| CHAMBRE | EN SERVICE | FT | 13 |
| POTEAU | EN SERVICE | FT | 12 |
| POTEAU | EN SERVICE | FT | 11 |
| CHAMBRE | EN SERVICE | FT | 10 |
| CHAMBRE | EN SERVICE |  | 1 |

Result for the sample data:

[image]